# android name application on google play is wrong, it take name package not the name of my application

Tags: android, manifest, launch

I published an application on play store with name "FIND PLACES NEARBY ME", but when I search it with his name I can't find it I find it only with the name findplacesnearbyme (package name) on play store.

On manifest file I'm sure I put the name FIND PLACES NEARBY ME on application name.

Thanks for your help

Here is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name="com.developer.android.library.searchPlaceAroundMe.receiver.ConnectivityReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.developer.android.library.searchPlaceAroundMe.receiver.PhoneStateReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.developer.android.library.searchPlaceAroundMe.receiver.SmsSentReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.developer.android.library.searchPlaceAroundMe.receiver.SmsSentReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.developer.android.library.searchPlaceAroundMe.receiver.SmsDeliveryReportReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.developer.android.library.searchPlaceAroundMe.receiver.SmsDeliveryReportReceiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.developer.android.library.searchPlaceAroundMe.receiver.BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action._BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.developer.android.searchPlaceNearByMe.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.developer.android.searchPlaceNearByMe.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.developer.android.searchPlaceNearByMe.Unrar"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_unrar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

With string app_name equal to  Find Places NearBy Me

Comment: Can you post your manifest? Thx.

Comment: i edit the first message with file manifest

Comment: I wanted to see what android:label was for your <application> and first <activity> node. In both cases it is string/app_name which I assume holds the correct name. So I am inclined to agree with the answers posted.

Answer (score 0):

Google play has a lot of ways when searching for an application, this includes title, description, package name etc.

When you search "FIND PLACES NEAR ME" it searches all applications that have these words in any area, this app name uses words that are used everyday so a lot of applications will get involved.

When you search findplacesnearbyme Google probably finds only your applications because no other applications has this "word" inside anywhere, while your application has it as package name.

Comment: I understand that, but i see all results of FIND PLACES NEAR ME and i didn't find my application. So the solution i have is change name of my application with a original name ?

Comment: I don't think that's needed, just publish your app's link on social networks (facebook, twitter etc) and as it gets more popularity it will show easier on search results. Now I'm not sure why your app doesnt show at all, I imagine if you search something like that it would have countless apps. On the other hand, I have an app with a unique name that when I search it I find it I find it, but nobody is going to "randomly search" that word so changing the name to something unique is not that much worth it. Just add a description and spread the word to friends and friends of friends!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to TomTsagk's answer, you could always provide the app description at google play with as many keywords as you can.

In some cases it's not possible to find your app according to "app_name" at google play. At least until you have some downloads.

The best way to find your app at play store by the time is published is adding your package name as a parameter to google play link.

i.e. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="your app package".

If i was in your place i would change the name with something not common as description.